# session.save_path doesn't work

Tags: php, apache, session

```
ini_set('session.save_path', __ROOT__ . '/sessions/');
echo 'needed: '.__ROOT__ . '/sessions/<br>curent: '.session_();
session_start();
```

this code shows:

```
needed: /var/www/admin/data/www/tdf/
curent: /var/www/admin/data/mod-tmp
```

ini_set didn't change path for sessions.
ISP Manager 5 lite installed.
This path  given by ISPM "/var/www/admin/data/mod-tmp".
Somehow ISP Manager block my changes.

I try to use .htaccess

```
php_value session.save_path = '/bla'
```

but it gives me Internal Server Error. On other servers this code works and gives the same path for "needed" and "curent"

whole code:

```
<?
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors', '1'); 
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 7776000); 
ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 7776000);
$path = '/var/www/admin/data/www/tdf/'; 
ini_set('session.save_path', $path); 
session_save_path($path); 
echo 'needed: '.$path. '<br>curent: '.session_save_path(); 
session_start(); 
$_SESSION['test'] = 'test';
phpinfo();
?>
```

.htaccess

```
php_value session.save_path /var/www/admin/data/www/
```

then, if I check phpinfo it shows me "session.gc_maxlifetime" been changed, but "session.save_path" no.

Comment: Try to use  this function instead [session_save_path](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-save-path.php)

Comment: What does your function `session_()` do. That may be relevant? Show that code as well!!

Comment: @user3848129 are you sure that your hosting allows you to change that value?

Comment: @Athafoud no, but its my own server

Comment: A "500 Internal Server Error" status code means: "please check the Apache logs for the exact error message". I suggest you do so. Whatever, I suspect you want to use Apache to change PHP directives but you don't run PHP as Apache module.

Comment: BTW, there's no way to say what's wrong with `session_()` if you don't post its code. Please edit the question and add it.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario error_logs says: "php_value takes two arguments, PHP Value Modifier", i fix that. Now it dint give me err500, but problem is.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario that is whole code:
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
if (!defined('__ROOT__')) define('__ROOT__', dirname(dirname(__FILE__)).'/public_html');
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 7776000);
ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 7776000);
echo ini_set('session.save_path', __ROOT__ . '/sessions/');
session_save_path(__ROOT__ . '/sessions/');
echo 'needed: '.__ROOT__ . '/sessions/<br>curent: '.session_save_path();
session_start();
$_SESSION['test'] = 'test';

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. Web-domain -> config -> change default to:

```
php_admin_value session.save_path "/var/www/admin/data/www/"
```

It forks on ISP Manager.